# Toggle readonly attribute in input field

Tags: jquery, button, uitextfield, toggle, readonly

I have created a form. Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nedzj/1/)**

By default all fields are in readonly state. What I need to do here is

1. Active the text field to edit when use click on the `Edit button` and edit button (Name and value) should turn into `SAVE button`.
2. Once editing is done user should click on the `Save button` and it should do the first step again, means change the button back to the original state i.e `Edit` and text fields to `readonly`

preferably looking for jquery solution.

Thank in advance!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gets all elements with the name `Edit` and attaches a click handler.
The variable `prev` is the previous input element and `ro` is that elements readonly attribute state (true / false).

Then we're setting the readonly state to `! ro` (not ro), which just means "set it to the opposite of what it currently is (a toggle function if you will)", and focusing the `prev` input.

The last line targets the currently clicked button with `this`, and changes it's text with a ternary operator based on the state of the `ro` variable.

```
$('[name="Edit"]').on('click', function() {
    var prev = $(this).prev('input'),
        ro   = prev.prop('readonly');
    prev.prop('readonly', !ro).focus();
    $(this).val(ro ? 'Save' : 'Edit');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nedzj/6/)

Comment: Could you please explain it

Comment: @Sowmya - Sure, explanation added!

Comment: thank you. One more thing, I need to show an alert called "Saved", next to the button, when I am done with editing (clicked on Save button). Please can you look at this.

Answer (score 6):

At its simplest:

```
// binds a click-handler to inputs whose `name` attribute is equal to 'Edit':
$('input[name="Edit"]').click(function(){
    // when the input is clicked, it looks to the previous input element
    // that has a `required` attribute, and sets its `readonly` property,
    // the `r` is the current readonly state (true or false)
    $(this).prev('input[required]').prop('readonly',function(i,r){
        // returns the value as the opposite  of what it currently is
        // if readonly is false, then it returns true (and vice-versa)
        return !r;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nedzj/5/).

And to provide for changing the text of the `button`:

```
$('input[name="Edit"]').click(function(){
    $(this)
    .val(function(i,v){
        return v === 'Edit' ? 'Finished' : 'Edit';
    })
    .prev('input[required]')
    .prop('readonly',function(i,r){
        return !r;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nedzj/7/).

Comment: Could you please explain it, what does it mean by !r and v